# How do I combine Vb.net project and Crypto Obfuscator to produce a protected program

Tags: vb.net, crypto-obfuscator

I have an existing VB project that uses InstallShield to create the instalation files. My 'solution' includes 2 projects (program and the instaler). What I would like to do is to use Crypto Obfuscator to protect the program. I have no idea where to start and the help file is very brief and unhelpful to my limited knowledge. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to integrate the obfuscation into your build process so that the assemblies are obfuscated immediately after they are built, and InstallShield is able to get and see obfuscated assemblies.

To integrate the obfuscation into your build process, from Crypto Obfuscator File Menu --> select "Visual Studio Project Integration Wizard" - run this wizard on your .sln and the integration is done.

If you need more help or info, please contact our support - we will be glad to help.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developer of [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm).

Comment: Thanks , its actually easy once you know how, I was looking it the wrong place.